# Converting Object to Map: Cast vs ObjectMapper

Tags: java, serialization, casting, jackson

What is the difference between below two methods of converting `Object` to `Map`? And which method is better, assuming both methods work for converting an `Object` to a `Map`?

Cast:

```
Object o = some object;
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) o;
```

ObjectMapper:

```
Object o = some object;
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue((String) o, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's depends what the input is.

- `(Map<String, Object>) o` is used for [casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) conversion, so the runtime type of `o` must be `Map`, otherwise `ClassCastException` will be thrown:

  ```
  Object o = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) o; // ok

  Object o = new ArrayList<>();
  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) o; //ClassCastException

  Object o = new String();
  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) o; //ClassCastException
  ```
- [`ObjectMapper().readValue(String content, JavaType valueType)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType)):

  > Method to deserialize JSON content from given JSON content String.

  which means the input should be a `String` in valid [json](https://www.json.org/) format. For example:

  ```
  Object input = "{\"key1\":{},\"key2\":{}}";
  Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue((String) input, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

  System.out.println(map.size()); // 2
  ```

Comment: Thanks. If both methods work for converting an Object to a Map, which one should I choose over the other?

Comment: That depends what your `Object` is. If it is a `String` in json format, you need `ObjectMapper`. If it is a `Map` instance refered by `Object`, you can just cast it by `(Map<String, Object>) o`

Answer (score 3):

There is no "better". There are practical differences. But first, both options use type casting, and this raises the question *"how are these two considered alternatives at all?"*

Casting will only work if `some object` passes the `instanceof Map` test (first option), or if `o` passes the `instanceof String` test (second option).

In other words, the answer depends on the runtime class of `some object`.

So either this will fail with a class cast exception:

```
(Map<String, Object>) o;
```

Or this will fail with the same exception:

```
(String) o
```

Assuming the type checks will pass one way or the other, there are differences to be considered:

- If `some object` is compatible with `Map<String, Object>`, then casting should be preferred as it offers a performance advantage (considering `objectMapper.convertValue` as the alternative). In fact, `readValue` isn't even an option as the cast to string will fail.
- If `some object` is a String, then you have no choice but to call `readValue`, as you need to parse JSON.

As noted above, there's also `objectMapper.convertValue`, which in a smart way checks first `instanceof` before performing the conversion through JSON parsing. It's meant to convert objects from one type to another, if the two types have the same fields.

Comment: It's even possible that *both* casts will fail, of course.